# Django annotate by foreign key's date field but exclude past dates

Tags: django, django-models

I want to have my queryset of `Card` model annotated with new field called available_on, which should be calculated as closest date in future of relative `Booking` model's field `removal_date`. It should consider only dates in future, how can I filter out removal_date dates that are in the past? What I have now is this.

```
def with_available_on(self):
    qs = self.annotate(available_on=Case(
        When(
            bookings_count__gt=0,
            slots_available__lt=1, 
            then=Min('bookings__removal_date')),
            default=None
        )
    )
    return qs
```

Also I want it to be calculated on database side if possible for performance purposes. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`filter=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter) to filter the objects over which you span the aggregate in the [**`Min`** aggregate [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#min):

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

def with_available_on(self):
        qs = self.annotate(available_on=Case(
            When(
                bookings_count__gt=0, slots_available__lt=1,
                then=Min(
                    'bookings__removal_date',
                    filter=Q(bookings__remval_date__gte=Now())
                )
            ),
            default=None)
        )
        return qs
```